# How to find all ideals of this factor ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

My question is about how to find all ideals of a factor ring.

> Let $J=((x+1)(x+2)(x+3)) \subset\mathbb C[x]$ and let $R=\mathbb C[x]/J$. I want to find all ideals in $R$ that contain $J$.

My thought is that $J$ is the zero element of $R$, so since any ideal in $R$ contains the zero element, $J$ should be a contained in any ideal if $R$. So if that's true I need to find every ideal of $R$.

But how can I do that? I know that $R$ is not a PID, so I can't even conclude that every ideal is principal. I also know that there is a one-to-one-correspondence between the ideals of $R$ that contain $J$ and the ideals of $R/J$. But I got really confused by that notion, because what is $(\mathbb C[x]/J)/J$? Isn't that just the same as $\mathbb C[x]/J$?

Really grateful for any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal of $R$ is of the form $I/J$ with $I\subset\mathbb C[x]$ an ideal containing $J$. The ideals of $\mathbb C[x]$ are principal, so $I=(f)$, $f\in\mathbb C[x]$. Since $J\subset I$ we have $f\mid (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$, so $f=\cdots$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the notation saying that every ideal in R is of the form $I/J$. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: @Rosters $R=S/J$, where $S$ is a ring which in this case happens to be $\mathbb C[x]$. Then how look the ideals of the factor ring $S/J$? They are in a one-to-one correspondence to the ideals of $S$ containing $J$ and this correspondence is exactly $I\to I/J$. (This is a fundamental result in your algebra course and it is necessary in order to find the ideals of factor rings.)

Comment: Okey, I think I get it. You're showing that the ideals in R are in one-to-one-correspondence with the ideals of $C[x]$ that contain J. So, I was right about that if I want to find all ideals in R that contain J it's the same as finding all ideals of R?

Comment: So, I'm thinking that the ideals in R that contain J are:
$(x+1)$,  $(x+2)$, $(x+3)$,  $(x+1)(x+2)$,  $(x+1)(x+3)$,  $(x+2)(x+3)$,  $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$ (which I guess is the trivial ideal, since it's equal to J which is the zero element of R, correct?) and then all of R. So 8 ideals all in all. Is that right?

Comment: I guess I should write: $(x+1)/J$ and so on. Is this the same as writing $(x+1 + J)$?

Comment: @Rosters To all your questions the answer is yes!

Answer (score 0):

By Chinese reminder theorem you get $C[x]/J\cong C[x]/(x-1)\times C[x]/(x-2)\times C[x]/(x-3)$. $(x-k)$ is maximal so $C[x]/(x-k)$ is a field. Now ideals in product of this fields are of the form $I_1\times I_2\times I_3$ where $I_j\in \{0, C[x]/(x-j)\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how do I know that ideals in the product of the fields are of that form?

Comment: Suppose you have ideal $I$ in $k_1\times k_2$ and there is element $(a,b)\in I$ such that $a\neq 0$ then $(a^{-1},0)(a,b)$ gives you that $k_1\times 0\subset I$. Can you end this proof?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'll give it a try. By a similar argument $0xk_2 \subset I$ so can I thereby conclude that $k_1xk_2 \subset I$? I don't know. I don't think I understand this. Can you give me another hint? And so, how do I go back to find the corresponding ideals in $R$?

Comment: If $I$ is any ideal in $k_1\times k_2 \times k_3$ if it contains any element $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ such that $a_1\neq 0$ then it contains whole $k_1\times 0\times0$ because $(a_1,0,0)=(a_1^{-1},a_2,a_3)(a_1,0,0)$. You can do the same for all $i$ and your done.

Comment: So, all in all there should be 8 ideals right? Including the trivial ideal and all of R?

Comment: Yes. I think so.